# GDB-Python scripting: any samples iterating through C/C++ struct fields

Tags: c++, python, c, scripting, gdb

The new [GDB-Python scripting API](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html) looks quite powerful and should be very useful. However writing a useful script to iterate through the fields in a struct of C or C++ is not trivial. Does any one know some solid samples that does exactly that?

Thanks in advance.

---

Update the final sample: Replace the `_print_fields()` in early sample.

```
    if l.type.code == gdb.TYPE_CODE_STRUCT:
        print "Found a struct  %s " % n
        #self._print_fields(n, t)
        self._print_deep_items(n, t, l)
    else:
        print "Found no struct"

def _print_deep_items (self, n_, type_, instance_):
    for fld in type_.fields():
        fn = fld.name
        ft = fld.type
        fv = instance_[fn]
        if fv.type.code == gdb.TYPE_CODE_STRUCT:
            print "  Found a sub struct  %s " % fn
            self._print_deep_items(fn, ft, fv)
        else:
            print "    Field %s " % fn, " type %s " % ft.tag, " value %s " % fv
```

And the output:

```
  variable s1   type S1
Found a struct  s1
    Field v1   type None   value 0
    Field v2   type None   value 0
  Found a sub struct  v3
    Field w3   type None   value 0
```

---

Update with the first sample: Got the following sample code working. This is not the optimal as it does a look-up on every field after composing the string field name. abarnert is showing a promising and elegant approach, the working code is updated in the above final update section.

```
import gdb
class PrintGList(gdb.Command):
    """print fields of a struct: wzd struct_object

Iterate through the fields of a struct, and display
a human-readable form of the objects."""
    def __init__(self):
        gdb.Command.__init__(self, "wzd", gdb.COMMAND_DATA, gdb.COMPLETE_SYMBOL, True)

    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):

        arg_list = gdb.string_to_argv(arg)
        if len(arg_list) < 1:
            print "usage: wzd struct"
            return

        n = arg_list[0]
        l = gdb.parse_and_eval(arg_list[0])
        m = l.type.tag

        print "  variable %s " % n, " type %s " % m
        try:
            t = gdb.lookup_type(m)
        except RuntimeError, e:
            print "type %s not found" % t
            return

        if l.type.code == gdb.TYPE_CODE_STRUCT:
            print "Found a struct  %s " % n
            self._print_fields(n, t)
        else:
            print "Found no struct"

    def _print_fields(self, n, typeobject):
        print typeobject
        flds = typeobject.fields()
        for x in flds:
            sn = n + "." + x.name
            print "  field %s" % sn, " code %s " % x.type.code, " type %s " % x.type.tag
            if x.type.code == gdb.TYPE_CODE_STRUCT:
                print "Found sub level struct  %s " % sn
                sl = gdb.parse_and_eval(sn)
                sm = sl.type.tag
                st = gdb.lookup_type( sm )
                self._print_fields(sn, x.type)

    def _deep_items (self, type_):
        for k, v in type_.iteritems():
            if k:
                print " k v %s " % k , " %s " % v
            else:
                print "   v    ",      " %s " % v

PrintGList()
```

The source file to test with:

```
struct S2 {        int w3;    };
struct S1 {        int v1, v2;      struct S2 v3; } s1;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {   return 0; }
```

Example output:

```
  variable s1   type S1
Found a struct  s1
S1
  field s1.v1  typecode 8   type None
  field s1.v2  typecode 8   type None
  field s1.v3  typecode 3   type S2
Found sub level struct  s1.v3
S2
  field s1.v3.w3  typecode 8   type None
```

GDB session to get the: 
    source /home/me/testpath/wzdfile.py
    file a.out
    b main
    r
    wzd s1
    quit

Comment: Have you tried looking through the Python source for the pretty-printers that come with gcc and gdb? There must be good examples there.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x, or 3.x? From what I can tell, gdb can now use either. And the gdb docs imply that types are effectively exposed as python `dict` objects. And the API for `dict` objects is different between the two versions. (For example, in 2.x, `iteritems()` returns a lazy iterator over key-value pairs, while `items()` returns a list of key-value pairs; in 3.x, `items()` returns a lazy iterator, and there is no `iteritems()`.)

Comment: python 2.6.6, gdb 7.2, on x86_64

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Types-In-Python.html#Types-In-Python), iterating through the fields of a C struct *should* be pretty trivial:

> If the type is a structure or class type, or an enum type, the fields of that type can be accessed using the Python dictionary syntax. For example, if `some_type` is a `gdb.Type` instance holding a structure type, you can access its foo field with:
>
> ```
> bar = some_type['foo']
> ```
>
> `bar` will be a `gdb.Field` object; see below under the description of the `Type.fields` method for a description of the `gdb.Field` class.

You can also use `Type.fields` to get the fields of a `struct` explicitly, but (as of 7.4) you can just use the normal [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) methods as well, so to get a list of name/`Field` pairs:

```
for name, field in foo.type.iteritems():
```

Or, for just the names:

```
for name, field in foo.type.iterkeys():
```

And so on.

This doesn't seem to be directly documented on that page, but [gdb.types](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/gdb_002etypes.html#gdb_002etypes) implies it pretty strongly when it says that `deep_items`:

> Returns a Python iterator similar to the standard gdb.Type.iteritems method.

For example, given this C type:

```
struct S {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

You can do this:

```
(gdb) python struct_S = my_s.type # or gdb.lookup_type("struct S"), etc.
(gdb) python print struct_S.keys()
{['a', 'b']}
(gdb) python print my_s['a']
0
```

From a quick glance at the [`types.py` source](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/gdb/python/lib/gdb/types.py?rev=1.8&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&cvsroot=src), look at how `gdb.types.deep_item(type_)` is implemented, and that does seem to be all there is to it.

---

Before gdb 7.4, you could not treat a type directly as a `dict`. That is, no `for name in instance_.type:` or `instance_.type.iteritems()`, etc. You had to explicitly call `fields`. Anyway, putting it all together, here's a simple example for iterating over all of the fields of a structure with gdb 7.2:

```
for field in inst.fields:
    fname = field.name
    ftype = field.type
    fval = inst[fname]
```

Except that this won't work if your `struct` has an anonymous `struct` inside it. For that, you'll need `deep_items` (and, if that isn't there in 7.2, you'll need to look at the code and figure out how to implement it yourself).

So, not *quite* trivial in 7.2, but pretty simple. And, if you want trivial, just upgrade to 7.4.

Comment: I'm looking for something "for x in fields(S): { print x.name, x.type; }", without knowing 'a', 'b' up-front. Thanks for the quick response, though! Actually tried both your example. For one got a missing "__dict__" or similar error, the another says gdb.Type object has no attribute iteritems. I'm not familiar with python.

Comment: @minghua: Well, Python doesn't put statements in braces, so your code isn't going to work… but I'm assuming you got past that, or you couldn't have gotten the errors you reported.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not 100% sure which bits you're refering to as my two examples, but if `iteritems` is raising an `AttributeError` while `keys` is working, my first guess is that you're using Python 3.x, and I've given you a 2.x answer. If so, let me know, and I can change it.

Comment: my python is 2.6.6, gdb 7.2 on x86_64. anyway, I got an example working, will post above. have not got the _deep_items working yet, will try later as it looks nicer. as you can see I'm a C programmer thus my earlier example is just to illustrate the logic.

Comment: Hi, I tried it again: "for name, field in foo.type.iteritems():", "for name, field in foo.type.iterkeys():", and "keys()". They all raise an "AttributeError".

Comment: @abarnet: This code piece: `print str(instance_)` shows `{v1 = 0, v2 = 0, v3 = {w3 = 0}}`. Probably it is trivial, but how do you traverse it? Once that is done, I guess I still need to get the type of each element. That should be all needed. I saw [this SO question about accessing GDB python Value keys and values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912338/how-to-access-the-keys-or-values-of-python-gdb-value) that is close but not exactly what I need.

Comment: @minghua: First, the reason you can't access the type directly as a `dict` is that you're using 7.2. If you upgrade to a later 7.x, the code in my answer will work. Otherwise, you have to explicitly call `fields()`.

Comment: @minghua: Second: You can't iterate directly over `instance_`; you have to iterate over `instance_.type` or `instance_.type.fields()` to get the names and types; then you can do `instance_[name]` for each name. Let me update my answer to include 7.2 examples (although I don't actually have 7.2, so this will be untested).

Comment: @minghua: I also added a few links. If you're not sure how to deal with dictionaries in Python, see http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries. Also, because you're not likely to guess things like `iteritems` on your own, fire up a regular Python interpreter and use the built-in help. You can, e.g., write `d={'key': 'value'}`, then `help(d)` to see all the things you can do with a `dict`.

Comment: Everything works! Thank you very much! The final sample is updated to the question section.

Comment: You may need to use `strip_typedefs()` on the type you have if you want to use `deep_items()`